# Permutations to satisfy a challenging restriction

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, pattern-recognition

> In a stack of n distinct cards in order {1,2,3,4,...,n} from top, define distance between 2
>   cards as the number of cards between them.
>   2 cards are neighbours if they're adjacent in original stack, if their index differs by 1.
>
> How many card rearrangements (permutations) satisfy the following?
>
> I)    **The sum of distances between any card and its 
>   neighbour/s** (call that sum $S_n$ for card $n$), **is distinct for all $n$
>   cards.**
>
> II)   **$S_n$ is distinct for all $n$ and only take on values smaller than $n$.**

---

**Edit 1**: an example makes the conditions clearer.

Say we have 3 cards in original stack in order 1,2,3 from top. Rearrange cards into order 2,3,1 from top. Then:

Card 1 is distance 1 from its former neighbour card 2. $S_1$=1

Card 2 is distance 1 to card 1 but distance 0 to card 3. $S_2$=1+0=1

Card 3 is distance 0 from card 2. $S_3$=0

Hence this reordering/shuffle does not satisfy the conditions in the question, as both $S_1$ and $S_2$ are 1.

---

**Edit 2**: JLee and LaBird kindly wrote programs to generate data(thanks so much!). Using the data I did a quick plot to guess possible relationships between n and the ratio of permutations satisfying condition 1 in respect to the total number of permutations of length n. This is a less than scientific approach, but in the spirit of contribution, i hope this can 'trigger' ways to solve the problem.

[image: ratio plot and log of ratio plot]

Brief comment: It appears that the slope of the log plot is stabilising to around -1/2, though this is a pure guess without more data.

---

My attempt: I made a list of basic observations, trying to link this problem to known methods, but to little success.

i)  Let original order of cards be 1,2,3,4…..,n for simplicity from top of stack . After the order of the cards are randomized, the distance between cards 2 and 3 will contribute to both S2 and S3, as they were neighbours before.

ii) The question is analogous to a frog making n-1 leaps on a 1*n board, labelled 1,2,3,4…..n from left to right. Starting on the square representing the new position of card 1, the frog makes leaps so that on the mth turn, the it is on the square representing the new position of the mth card. The restrictions are that every square must be covered exactly once and the magnitude of the first and last leaps, and the sum of the magnitudes of any 2 consecutive leaps must be distinct.

iii)    Cards 1 and n have only 1 neighbour, so after rearranging, S1 and Sn are the distances between card 1 and its former neighbour and card n and its former neighbour, respectively.

iv) In part i) Sn can take on any value from 0 to 2n-5. If a card k stays adjacent to its neighbours, then Sk=0. If Sn>n-3 for some n, then we can deduce that the former neighbouring cards are now both above or both below card n Sn reaches a maximum value of 2n-5 when a card is on the bottom of the deck and its two former neighbours at the top of the deck. Only n of those values need to be used so n-4 will remain unused.

v)  For part ii), Sn can take on only values from 0 to n-1. Hence every value must be taken once. This means exactly one card k must remain next to all of its former neighbors in the new arrangement. This is done so Sk can take on the value 0. I’m not sure if such an arrangement is even possible.

vi) At n=4, there are exactly 4 possible values for Sn : (0,1,2,3). For every greater value of n, the possible values of Sn exceeds n.

Are there existing strategies to analyze/tackle problems like this? Can this problem be solved for small n like n=5?

thanks as always

Comment: Define neighbor. Also, it feels like some needed details are left out. I understand the frog equivalent, I think.

Comment: 2 cards are neighbours if they are adjacent in the stack.

Comment: former neighbors? each card has either 1 or 2 neighbors. what are former neighbors? are they shuffled and thus the neighbors that they used to have are former neighbors?

Comment: So in the original stack the top and bottom cards will have one adjacent card (neighbour), while cards in the middle of the deck will have two. Yes, after being shuffled, 'former neighbours' are neighbours the card used to have.

Comment: But there is nothing at all about shuffling the cards in any way in the question. only permutations.

Comment: The question asks how many permutations of the n cards satisfy these conditions. 'Shuffle' is just used to demonstrate what distance to former neighbour means, it does not always generate a valid permutation. Say we have 3 cards in original stack in order 1,2,3 from top. If we rearrange the cards into order 2,3,1 from top, then card 1 is distance 1 from its former neighbour card 2. Card 2 is distance 0 to card 3 but distance 1 to card 1. Card 3 is distance 0 from card 2. Hence this reordering/shuffle does not satisfy the conditions in the question, S1=1, S2=0+1=1, S3=0. (1 has appeared twice)

Comment: Driven by curiosity, I wrote a program to see what happens when $n \ge 4$. When $n = 4$, there are $4$ permutations that satisfy the condition ($(1,3,4,2), (2,4,3,1), (3,1,2,4), (4,2,1,3)$), but no solution exists for $n = 5, 6$ or $7$. When $n = 8$, there are $92$ permutations that satisfy the condition, while for $n = 9$, there are $132$ permutations. Finally when $n = 10$, no solution exists! While I believe it is difficult to solve the problem in general, an obvious observation is that the number of permutations that satisfy the condition must always be an even number due to symmetry.

Comment: Since there is some momentum on unravelling this question, does anyone know of other users who would be potentially interested in further analysing this question? Is it polite to tag others on SE?

Comment: A couple of comments on wording. (1) Do "is distinct for all $n$" and "is different for all $n$" mean different things? If not, just write this once. (2) The phrase "all its former neighbors" is a confusing way of saying "its former neighbor" for a card from the top or bottom and "both neighbors" for all others. The word "all" can prompt someone to expect more than two in some cases. It might be better to first explicitly define _neighbor_, then write "its former neighbor(s)" to mean "the one or two cards that were its former neighbors".

Comment: @DavidK you raised good points. I have improved the wording according to both suggestions. I just wanted to avoid too many definitions in the statement of question, though this one is probably better defined at the start.

Answer (score 2):

***This is not a full answer, but I hope this answer can trigger some thoughts for better answers.***

There are two observations I've made:

(1) The number of permutations that satisfy the conditions must be an even number (including $0$). The reason is by symmetry. If ($X_1, X_2, X_3, \dots, X_{n-2}, X_{n-1}, X_n$) is an answer, then ($X_n, X_{n-1}, X_{n-2}, \dots, X_3, X_2, X_1$) must also be an answer.

(2) For $n = 4p+2$ or $n = 4p+3$ where $p$ is an non-negative integer, there will be no solution. The reason is that $\sum S_i$ must be an even number, since when card $x$ is having a distance of $d$ from its former neighbor $y$, $y$ is also having the same distance $d$ from $x$. And this distance $d$ is counted twice -- once inside $S_x$ and once inside $S_y$. Therefore $\sum S_i$ must be an even number. However, condition (II) of the question requires that $\sum S_i = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}$. This number is odd when $n = 4p+2$ or $n = 4p+3$ (i.e. $n = 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, \dots$). Hence there will be no solution.

Surely, this does not explain why $n = 5$ has no solution (according to my brute-force attempt using a computer program), and how to find the number of permutations that satisfy the condition when $n = 4p$ or $n = 4p+1$.

***Added the following after reading the comments from OP:***

(1) In fact, we can make a stronger claim that the number of permutations that satisfy the conditions must be a multiple of $4$ (including $0$). The reason is as follows:

If ($X_1, X_2, X_3, \dots, X_{n-2}, X_{n-1}, X_n$) is an answer (call it [a]), then ($X_n, X_{n-1}, X_{n-2}, \dots, X_3, X_2, X_1$) must also be an answer (call it [b]) according to symmetry.

Also, if [a] is an answer, ($n+1-X_1, n+1-X_2, n+1-X_3, \dots, n+1-X_{n-2}, n+1-X_{n-1}, n+1-X_n$) is an answer too (call it [c]). In this case, if we express every $S_i$ in [a] and [c] as two sequences, these two sequence will be exactly the reverse of each other. An example is when $n=4$, as ($1, 3, 4, 2$) is an answer, ($4, 2, 1, 3$) is also an answer (just replacing $i$ as $n+1-i$).

So, if [c] is an answer, then ($n+1-X_n, n+1-X_{n-1}, n+1-X_{n-2}, \dots, n+1-X_3, n+1-X_2, n+1-X_1$) is an answer too (call it [d]), by symmetry to [c].

Now, the only thing we need to prove is that we won't double count the same permutation twice or more. For the above $4$ answers, it may happen that [a] is actually the same permutation as [d], or [b] is actually the same permutation as [c]. This happens when $X_i + X_{n+1-i} = n-1$ for every $i \in [1,n]$. But in such case, the answer will NOT satisfy condition II. The proof is as follows:

If $X_i + X_{n+1-i} = n-1$ for every $i \in [1,n]$, this means when card $1$ is at position $j$ (assume the first card is denoted as position $1$), card $n$ is at position $n+1-j$. Similarly, when card $2$ is at position $k$, card $n-1$ is at position $n+1-k$. Now consider the sum $S_1$, which is actually the distance between card $1$ and card $2$, hence $S_1 = |j-k|-1$. Next, consider the sum $S_n$, which is actually, the distance between card $n$ and card $n-1$, hence $S_n = |(n+1-j)-(n+1-k)|-1 = |j-k|-1$ ($n+1$ must be larger than $j$ and $k$). As $S_1 = S_n$, the solution does not satisfy condition I or II. This applies to any of the $4$ solutions [a], [b], [c] and [d], as long as [a]=[d] or [b]=[c]. So we can safely claim that there is no double-counting, hence the number of permutations that satisfy both conditions must be a multiple of $4$.

Comment: +1 ! Nice observations, especially #2! The two contributions so far makes me wonder whether permutations with the second properties all have length in multiples of 4. Too early to say but i'll have another scribble tonight. Also @JLee did find permutations which satisfied condition I for n=5,6 and 7.

Comment: Not sure your meaning of "all have length in multiples of $4$", but if you are referring to $\sum S_i$, then there already exists a counter example, which is $n=4$, where $\sum S_i$ equals $6$.

Comment: I meant the length of permutations which satisfy the second condition seem to be multiples of 4. E.g. 4 permutations of length 4 (1342 etc.) and 52 permutations of length 8 satisfy the second condition. I wonder if there is a good reason why or whether there are any tools to find out why?

Comment: Your point is good. When $(X_1, X_2, ... X_{n-1}, X_n)$ is an answer (a), $(X_n, X_{n-1}, ... X_2, X_1)$ is also an answer (b) by symmetry. Now $(N+1-X_1, N+1-X_2, ... N+1-X_{n-1}, N+1-X_n)$ is also an answer (c) (in this case, the sequence of $S_i$'s is the reverse of that in answer (a) and (b). And it follows that $(N+1-X_n, N+1-X_{n-1}, ... N+1-X_2, N+1-X_1)$ is also a solution (d) by symmetry to (c). So it is likely that the no. of permutations that satisfy condition II is a multiple of $4$. But we have to avoid double counting in case the pairs (a)(d) and (b)(c) are actually the same.

Comment: After some thoughts, in fact we can also prove that when (a)(d) or (b)(c) are the same, these four are NOT solutions at all (they cannot satisfy condition II). So you are right, the no. of permutations that satisfy condition II is a multiple of $4$. I will work out the proof later on.

Comment: This is very interesting as now we can work in units of 4. If we consider 4 related permutations as equivalent, n=4 has 1 equivalence class and n=8 has 23. I'm currently trying to see if only stacks of 4,8, 12, 16,....4n cards can have permutations satisfying condition II. It would also be interesting to see how many permutations satisfy condition 2 at n=12. As much as this problem seems to be difficult to solve in general, much has been unravelled! It remains a mystery to find the general pattern in the number of permutations that satisfy both conditions.

Comment: a density plot has been added in JLee's section. The plot might interest you as it reflects some of the results you've proven!

Comment: I am not sure if we can find out a formula by using generating functions or other methods at this stage. The few data points may not give us enough clue, and it can be more complicated if the formulas are different for the cases $n = 4p$ and $n = 4p+1$. In the worst case, it looks like the formula may be partially related to $n!$, which is more or less the same complexity as $n^n$, and for the numbers we have found, $92 = 4 \times 23$, and $4204 = 4 \times 1051$, and both $23$ and $1051$ are primes, so the functions will not simply be $n!$ or $c^n$ or $n^c$, it may be a mix of them.

Comment: good observations there. We probably don't have the correct specialised tools to figure that out. Questions with colourful and meaningful diagrams seem to attract many more viewers than one that is dense with text. I wonder if there are good tools for drawing something relevant to this question. Do you have a good intuitive diagram in mind which helped you understand this question? Maybe this way we'd be blessed by some of the very smart people on SE taking a glimpse at this question.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have such a diagram in mind. But you may simplify the question, instead of cards shuffling, you may just consider an array of integers from $1$ to $n$, such that $P(i) = $(difference in position of $i$ and $(i+1)) - 1 $ when $i=1$, or (difference in position of $i$ and $(i-1)) - 1$ when $i=n$, or difference in position of $i$ and $(i-1)) - 1 + $ (difference in position of $i$ and $(i+1)) - 1 $ when $1 \lt i \lt n$.

Comment: New idea: start with permutation ($X_1, X_2, X_3, \dots, X_{n-2}, X_{n-1}, X_n$) satisfying condition 1. Insert card n+1 into position j. Then $S_1$’ to $S_(n+1)$’ will change in the following way from previous set $S_1$ to $S_n$. For 0<i<n $S_i$’=$S_i$ if none of card i’s neighbours are separated from card i by card n+1, $S_i$’= $S_i$+1 if one neighbour is separated and $S_i$’=$S_i$+2 if both neighbours are separated. $S_n$’=$S_n$+$S_n+1$’ and $S_n+1$’ is new. If all new distances are distinct then this is a  valid permutation of length n+1. Call this 'extending' a permutation.

Comment: Now think of 'completing' a permutation. If we have a permutation of length n which doesn't satisfy condition 1 but by adding card n+1 into certain position/s, this will 'complete' the permutation into one satisfying condition 1. The process by which the Si' is generated is identical to the description above. Now all permutations of length n+1 satisfying condition 1 must be able to be generated by at least one of these 2 methods (extension and completion). I wonder if this can generate some form of recursive formula? How does this fare with condition 2?

Answer (score 1):

This also is not a full answer, but it gives the data for up to n=9, and maybe it can be used to see a pattern, and then create a formula based on n.

**3-21-2015: Correction: n=8, Cond 1 was incorrect. It said 412, but the correct count is 532
[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the list of 92 permutations that satisfy condition 2 for n = 8.

[image]

Here is the list of 132 permutations that satisfy condition 2 for n = 9.

[image]

The triangle below gives the counts of the permutations meeting condition 1, for each n, split up according to the first character in the permutation. For example, for n=6, there is 1 Conditon-1-permutation starting with 1, 3 Condition-1-permutations starting with 2, 2 Condition-1-permutations starting with 3, and so on.... (Thanks to LaBird for the data where n>=10)

[image]

I generated the list of permutations with a small C# program, and then plugged it into Excel and did the rest of the calculation in the spreadsheet. I can calculate this for larger n values if you think it would help.

Comment: @LaBird's observed that permutations satisfying the second condition must have length 4n and 4n+1. Is there a nice property of stacks of length of multiples of 4 that can satisfy these properties? Could you use your program to investigate n=12 and n=13, if it is not too tedious?

Comment: It is also interesting how for n=5, Sn=3 does not appear in any valid permutations. For n=6, two of (0,2,4,6) are left out of all valid permutations.

Comment: The brute force method provided very valuable insights into possible things we can prove about this problem!

Comment: Inspired by @JLee's comment, a colour coded plot of the **density** of favourable permutations divided by total permutations might provide insights into a pattern. One plot that came to mind was one in the shape of a triangle, where the nth row has n squares.The ith square (from left) in the nth row will represent: (number of permutations of length n satisfying Cond.I, starting with i)/(total number of permutations of length n). E.g. 2nd square in 6th row will be 3/5!, as there are 3 permutations of length 6 starting with 2 satisfying cond I out of 5!. No obligation as maybe time consuming.

Comment: The symmetry down the centre was predicted. The distribution on each side seems skewed towards the centre. Then we have the weird case at n=7 when more permutations starting from 1 satisfied condition I than those starting with 2.

Comment: Here's what I've worked out for $n=10$ to $13$. Let $P_1(n)$ denote the no. of permutations that satisfy Cond I, and $Q_1(n,i)$ denote the no. of permutations that starts with $i$ and satisfy Cond I. $P_1(10)=11368, Q_1(10,i)=(567, 1008, 1496, 1405, 1208, 1208, 1405, 1496, 1008, 567)$; $P_1(11)=77736, Q_1(11,i)=(3440, 6291, 8680, 8724, 7813, 7840, 7813, 8724, 8680, 6291, 3440)$.

Comment: $P_1(12)=552700$, $Q_1(12,i)=(22701, 39367, 55199, 55058, 52137, 51888, 51888, 52137, 55058, 55199, 39367, 22701)$; $P_1(13)=4411144$, $Q_1(13,i)=(166448, 286846, 396693, 399653, 379560, 385158, 382428, 385158, 379560, 399653, 396693, 286846, 166448)$.

Comment: I also found $4204$ permutations satisfying both conditions for $n=12$, and $14408$ for $n=13$. However, I can't spot any trend or work out any formulas from these results here. And it seems my brute-force computer program has reached its limit, as it will spend too much time to find out results for larger $n$ (such as $16$).

Comment: Maybe we can come up with a generating function...

Comment: I added 2 plots to summarise the data so far to the main body using your data. Does it trigger any ideas about what the generating function could be? If one exists I suspect it is an exponential one.

Comment: I've got nothing. I think it will take someone much smarter than me to get a pattern out of this data, but I think someone here on this site can do it. There are so many math geniuses here. I guess the trick is getting them to look at it.

Comment: I was reading about derangements recently. They can define a recursive formula in terms of a smaller n, and also find a neat formula for the number of derangements of n objects=!n={nearest integer (n!/e)}.

Comment: It seems like it would be easier to get a formula for the condition 1 column numbers, than for the numbers in the triangle.

Comment: @JLee I figure to attract more people to view this, it would be good to make a diagram to represent what distance means for example. Do you know any good tools for drawing clear coloured diagrams?

Comment: I do most stuff for this site in Excel, but Visio might be good, or Photoshop, or, if it's really basic, MS Paint. Another idea is to rewrite the question by summarizing what you've got so far, and posting it as a new question that focuses on getting a formula or generating function for your data. If you do this, use the diagrams in that question, and you might want to include a link to this question, in case people want to go back to the beginning. Lastly, look up tags and make sure that you have included all relevant tags, because that is how people find the questions that they want to view.

Comment: @JLee thanks for through advice. It would make the question better focused and less cluttered. If you had an intuitive diagram for the question you think would attract more people to look at it, please share it. Also mind if I use your work with credit when I start the new question?

Comment: You can use anything I have posted, and if you want to download the 2 Excel files I have, let me know and I will put them on my ftp server for you. It's bedtime now, but I will try to remember to create a graphic for you tomorrow.